# is there a way to define a text_field element type that does send_key as default set

Tags: page-object-gem

I'm using the page-object-gem and the populate_page_with methods along with the datamagic gem.
I have several text_fields in my application under test that require send_keys of a value and then send_keys :tab.
The application just does not work if I set the value through the default method of the text_field element.

When I encounter one of these send key type fields I just stub out a method in the page class as follows:

```
class SampleThing

   include  PageObject
   include  PageObject::PageFactory
   include  DataMagic

   text_field(:dos_start, :id => 'DOSStart')
   text_field(:beg_page, :id => 'BegPage')
   text_field(:end_page, :id => 'EndPage')


  def populate_page(datakey)
     my_data = data_for datakey
     self.set_dos_start(my_data['dos_start']) 
     self.beg_page= my_data['beg_page']
     self.end_page= my_data['end_page'] 
  end

  def set_dos_start(my_data)
     self.dos_start_element.send_keys my_data
     self.dos_start_element.send_keys :tab
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to dry up this and create a custom element type that would allow me to define this in the page object and in essence eliminate the need for me to code out the popuate_page?

```
 sendkey_field(:dos_start, :id => 'DOSStart')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the widget feature to create your own control and accessor. When defining a widget, by default it only creates methods to return the element and check that it is present. However, you can use the `accessor_methods` to define additional methods that will be created for the page object - in this case, a setter method.

The control would be created/registered as follows. Note that you want the setter method to be called `#{name}=` so that it can be used in the `populate_page_with` method.

```
class SendkeyField < PageObject::Elements::TextField
  def self.accessor_methods(accessor, name)
    accessor.send(:define_method, "#{name}=") do |value|
      self.send("#{name}_element").send_keys(value, :tab)
    end
  end
end

PageObject.register_widget :sendkey_field, SendkeyField, :text_field
```

This would give you the desired accessor:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  sendkey_field(:dos_start, :id => 'DOSStart')
end
```

As well as the ability to set the field individually:

```
page.dos_start = 'value'
```

Or using the built-in `populate_page_with` method:

```
page.populate_page_with(dos_start: 'value')
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, this is exactly what I as looking for